# EMF: Generate Editor Code

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-emf, emf

I just started using Eclipse Modeling Framework (EMF), and I'm having some troubles with the following tutorial:

http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/EclipseEMF/article.html

Everything was going smooth until I tried to Generate Editor Code (step 5.1). When I did that, the newly generated code just came out filled of errors because Eclipse couldn't find most of the required classes. I already imported EMF libraries from multiple ways, but probably my problem is that I'm not using the correct ones. Can anyone tell me where to download the correct ones? Or simply spot what I may be doing wrong? Below you have the list of imports that are messing up with Eclipse....

Thanks in advance!

EDIT: I am supposed to use RAP as a target application!

```
import org.eclipse.emf.common.ui.viewer.IViewerProvider;

import org.eclipse.emf.edit.ui.action.ControlAction;
import org.eclipse.emf.edit.ui.action.CreateChildAction;
import org.eclipse.emf.edit.ui.action.CreateSiblingAction;
import org.eclipse.emf.edit.ui.action.EditingDomainActionBarContributor;
import org.eclipse.emf.edit.ui.action.LoadResourceAction;
import org.eclipse.emf.edit.ui.action.ValidateAction;

import org.eclipse.jface.action.Action;
import org.eclipse.jface.action.ActionContributionItem;
import org.eclipse.jface.action.IAction;
import org.eclipse.jface.action.IContributionItem;
import org.eclipse.jface.action.IContributionManager;
import org.eclipse.jface.action.IMenuListener;
import org.eclipse.jface.action.IMenuManager;
import org.eclipse.jface.action.IToolBarManager;
import org.eclipse.jface.action.MenuManager;
import org.eclipse.jface.action.Separator;
import org.eclipse.jface.action.SubContributionItem;

import org.eclipse.jface.viewers.ISelection;
import org.eclipse.jface.viewers.ISelectionChangedListener;
import org.eclipse.jface.viewers.ISelectionProvider;
import org.eclipse.jface.viewers.IStructuredSelection;
import org.eclipse.jface.viewers.SelectionChangedEvent;
import org.eclipse.jface.viewers.Viewer;

import org.eclipse.ui.IEditorPart;
import org.eclipse.ui.PartInitException;
```

Comment: are you using eclipse for EMF developers?

Comment: No, standard... Nice tip! I'll give it a try, I'm struggling with this for far too long

Comment: it's so much easier :-) I've worked with this some years ago but I haven't the tutorial I've wrote. It's probably somewhere in the CVS of the company I've worked before... I'll try to get it again and make it public somewhere. Until then, I recommend you the EMF book. It's old and it was very useful for me http://www.amazon.com/EMF-Eclipse-Modeling-Framework-Edition/dp/0321331885

Comment: For some reason, I am unable to run eclipse for EMF developers... But I already fixed it (see my answer)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally got rid from the errors. To do that, I just needed to check the Rich Ajax Platform flag under the  genmodel Properties view, as shown in the screenshot below:

[image]